# ActiveMQ Artemis does not respect broker.xml settings for queue deletion and queue configuration

Tags: amqp, activemq-artemis

I'm running ActiveMQ Artemis 2.28.0 with a broker config as shown below. I left the things in which I think are relevant (mainly default settings).

I am sure the file is actually used because if I disable auto-create-queues for example I do get errors as expected, but other settings just seem to be ignored in my use case.

```xml
<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
               xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">
   <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">

      <address-settings>
         <!-- if you define auto-create on certain queues, management has to be auto-create -->
         <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
         </address-setting>
         <!--default for catch all-->
         <address-setting match="#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <max-size-messages>-1</max-size-messages>
            <page-size-bytes>10M</page-size-bytes>
            <max-read-page-messages>-1</max-read-page-messages>
            <max-read-page-bytes>20M</max-read-page-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-delete-queues>false</auto-delete-queues>
            <auto-delete-addresses>false</auto-delete-addresses>

            <auto-delete-created-queues>false</auto-delete-created-queues>
            <default-exclusive-queue>false</default-exclusive-queue>
            <default-max-consumers>-1</default-max-consumers>

         </address-setting>
      </address-settings>

      <address-queue-scan-period>-1</address-queue-scan-period>

      <addresses>
         <address name="DLQ">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="DLQ" />
            </anycast>
         </address>
         <address name="ExpiryQueue">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="ExpiryQueue" />
            </anycast>
         </address>
      </addresses>
   </core>
</configuration>
```

With these settings I have following expectations:

- queues are auto-created when needed
- when a consumer stops listening to a queue both the queue and the address still exists
- more than one consumer can join the queue if necessary

However, the behaviour I observe is as follows:

- when creating a (multicast) consumer the queue is automatically created
- the created queue has a maxConsumerCount of `1` even though the default is set to `-1`
- when I close my session both the queue and the address are deleted, even though the queue has `auto-delete-queues` set to `false`

As a possible workaround I also added the `address-queue-scan-period` value but this doesn't make a difference in the observed behaviour.

This is a trace of creation which shows the incorrect maxConsumers value

```
2023-06-15 15:56:05,251 DEBUG [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.plugin.impl] AMQ843006: beforeCreateQueue called with queueConfig: QueueConfiguration [id=null, name=C7GN9YMV1P53I5PI.receiver, address=linda.acc.train.behaviour.12, routingType=MULTICAST, filterString=SubscriptionId='C7GN9YMV1P53I5PI' OR SubscriptionId IS NULL, durable=null, user=admin, maxConsumers=1, exclusive=false, groupRebalance=false, groupRebalancePauseDispatch=false, groupBuckets=-1, groupFirstKey=null, lastValue=false, lastValueKey=null, nonDestructive=false, purgeOnNoConsumers=false, enabled=true, consumersBeforeDispatch=0, delayBeforeDispatch=-1, consumerPriority=null, autoDelete=false, autoDeleteDelay=0, autoDeleteMessageCount=0, ringSize=-1, configurationManaged=null, temporary=null, autoCreateAddress=true, internal=null, transient=null, autoCreated=null]
```

When the consumer is closed below log indicates the queue and the address is destroyed which does not match with my settings.

```
2023-06-15 15:56:35,559 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.plugin.impl] AMQ841006: closed consumer ID: 0, with  consumer Session: 5ef8b4b4-0b84-11ee-be26-d6283bc2e653, failed: false
2023-06-15 15:56:35,568 DEBUG [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.plugin.impl] AMQ843007: beforeDestroyQueue called with queueName: C7GN9YMV1P53I5PI.receiver, session: ServerSessionImpl(), checkConsumerCount: true, removeConsumers: false, autoDeleteAddress: true
```

At this point I don't really know if I'm running against a bug or if I'm misunderstanding the setup parameters.

Comment: What client library are you using? Is it Qpid JMS?

Comment: Currently I'm validating with libraries that should respect main amqp protocol. Tested with github.com/Azure/go-amqp in Go and Microsoft.Azure.Amqp in C# currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have misunderstood the automatic address & queue creation functionality. Automatic address & queue creation only applies in situations where the address or queue *wouldn't be created otherwise for normal operation*. For example if a JMS producer sent a message to a JMS queue that didn't already exist in `broker.xml` then with the default settings the corresponding address & anycast queue would be created and the message would be stored in that queue.

That said, technically speaking queues are automatically created in multicast (i.e. pub/sub) use-cases regardless of the auto-create settings in `broker.xml`. The documentation typically refers to these queues as "subscription queues." For example, if a JMS consumer subscribed to a JMS topic whose corresponding address was already configured in `broker.xml` then a multicast queue for the consumer's subscription would be created automatically regardless of the auto-creation configuration. This is because the subscription queue is *required* for normal multicast semantics. If subscription queues weren't automatically created then you would have to manually configure the multicast queue in `broker.xml` for every subscriber which is unrealistic. Historically speaking, this behavior existed long before there was any other notion of address & queue auto-creation.

Furthermore, certain settings are applied to subscription queues regardless of the configuration of the `default-*` `address-settings` (e.g. `default-max-consumers`, `default-exclusive`). This is due to the nature of the particular subscription queue. For example, in JMS subscriptions can be shared or unshared & durable or non-durable. Unshared subscription queues have a max-consumer count of `1` because they are never supposed to be shared (i.e. have > 1 consumer).

Comment: Thanks for this info, is there a way to manage these subscription queues? The end goal is as follows:
- queues (and addresses) are created on-demand
- if consumers lose connection and reconnect they should receive the data which was sent inbetween
=> currently this fails because either the address disappears on 'full' disconnect or on reconnect (same clientid and same queue name) we hit errors with the max-consumers (this is why I tried to change that parameter)

Comment: If you want the queue to have a max-consumers = -1 (i.e. unlimited) then you should set the `shared` capability when you connect.